# Spotify API: Can I retrieve users who have an artist / track in their playlists?

Tags: r, api, spotify

I'm using the Spotify API in R with the package `Rspotify`. Is there a way to retrieve a list of users who are interested in a specific artist / album / band? For example, getting a vector of ids that have track "6fQVr0vmoQRpOY3mRcoWIC" in their playlists.

All the commands seem to give information when you already have the user, but not the other way round. Does anyone have an idea how to get this?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible, because, in order to get a users data, they have to grant you permission first. Once you've got the users permission to see their data, you'll be able to go through their playlists to find the artists and tracks that are included.

Comment: In fact, the Spotify API lets you get playlists and profiles from a user, as long as you provide the userid (https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-list-users-playlists/). My question is if it's possible to get a list of users based on an artist or track.